# <Select> dropdown orders numbers incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select dropdown which is dynamically populated with filenames from our server, on the server directory everything is ordered correctly.

But on the dropdown, it numbers higher integers above lower e.g. Australia #11 comes after Australia #100 etc, as shown in image.

Whilst I understand how to change order when it's  in html, I'm not sure if this is possible when it's dynamically populated?

Also shown images which show it ordered correctly in directory but not in dropdown.

Dropdown:

[image]

Directory:

[image]

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: Can you show us your code please

Comment: sure it's literally just a dropdown -  <select class="form-control" name="ovpn-filename" id="ovpn-filename"></select> dropdown

Comment: "Australia #11 comes after Australia #100" well, that's correct, if it's ordered lexicographically

Comment: May be that is due to, you get data in an object format.... You should get data in array.... show us data you get from server

Comment: @Nihal updated with image

Answer (score 1):

The list is sorted alphabetically, so "**#11**" comes after "**#10**9".

To fix this, you can write your own sort function to consider only the numerical part instead of the whole string. That way it gets sorted numerically and not alphabetically. Here's a quick ES6 solution.

```
let countryList  =    [/*list here*/];

countryList      =    countryList.sort( (eachLine, prevLine) => eachLine.split("#")[1].split(" ")[0] - prevLine.split("#")[1].split(" ")[0] );
```

This simply sorts it based on the number part of the string alone and ignores the rest.